# Greedy Search from point A to point B on a graph

Tags: search, graph, greedy

A question in my textbook asked me to calculate and find a route from Mehadia to Bucharest via 1) A Greedy Search and 2) A uniform-cost search.

*Now I am able to completely illustrate and solve the route via uniform cost search but my greedy search is looking very similar. Any ideas on how I can calculate the route via a "greedy" search?

[image: Map]

**UPDATE**
I've applied a messy greedy algotithm and have gotten a different route vs the shortest route from my uniform-cost.

This is the route outputted by my greedy algorithm. The algorithm just keep checking and choosing the smallest local value. My NEW QUESTION to anyone: Is this route acceptable as an output of my greedy algorithm? I.e. could my solution even be legally considered as greedy?

Route based on my new algorithm:

Mehadia -> Lugoj -> Timisoara -> Arad -> Zerind -> Oradea -> Sibiu -> 
Rimnicu Vilcea -> Pitesti -> Bucharest

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand the actual question; please describe your algorithm in more detail. It sounds a bit as if you have rediscovered the algorithm by [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm), which is greedy in the sense that some smallest current minimum is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **Uniform-cost Search** you are calculating shortest paths from Mehadia to all nodes, so you can be certain the Mehadia-Bucharest path will be the optimal one (this algorithm is complete and optimal).
However if you use a **Greedy Search Algorithm**, it will choose the locally best
option discarding the others for each node. This algorithm is neither complete nor optimal.
To answer your question yes, your solution is considered as greedy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: okay thanks a lot mate...because when I worked it out via uniform cost search i got the route: (Mehadia -> Drobeta ->   Craiova -> Pitesti -> Bucharest)...And for the greedy search algorithm I kept choosing the cheapest edge without backtracking. It seemed a little too easy that's why I asked if my solution of "Mehadia -> Lugoj -> Timisoara -> Arad -> Zerind -> Oradea -> Sibiu -> Rimnicu Vilcea -> Pitesti -> Bucharest" would have been considered greedy and should possibly accepted as a "greedy" search. Thanks again!